Reading each cell value in a table in manim
I have created a table using Table in manim, and i want to simply read the value in one of the cells.
As an example imagine i have written "a" in row 0 column 0, i want to say:
If mytable.get_rows()[0][0] == "a":
   mytable.get_rows()[0][0].set_color(RED)

you see, its not necessarily changing the color that i want, that was just an example. I want to be able to read a table cell to compare it, when i try to print it, it prints vmobjectsvgpath, i tried many different things like str method to convert it to string or using get_ entries(), but none of them works, this is a problem that is seen in Text as well.
I asked AI but didnt get a good answer, answers were more like try get_tex_string() or .text() ,... where either do not exist or do not work.
I explained above that i tried many different methods, but none of them work.

dir() is your friend.
Use it to learn the set of attributes you can ask for help() about.
>>> from pprint import pp
>>> from manim import Table, Text
>>> 
>>> t0 = Table(
...             [["This", "is a"],
...             ["simple", "Table in \n Manim."]])
>>> 
>>> t0.get_rows()[0][1]
Paragraph(VGroup of 3 submobjects)
>>> 
>>> t0.get_rows()[0][1].color
ManimColor('#FFFFFF')
>>>
>>> t0.get_rows()[0][1].lines_text
Text('is a')
>>> 
>>> pp(dir(t0.get_rows()[0][1]))
['__abstractmethods__',
 '__add__',
 '__class__',
 ...
 'updaters',
 'updating_suspended',
 'width',
 'z_index']
>>> 
>>> str(t0.get_rows()[0][1].lines_text)
"Text('is a')"
>>> 
>>> str(t0.get_rows()[0][1].lines_text).split("'")[1]
'is a'
>>> 
>>>
>>> txt = Text('Hello world')
>>> 
>>> txt.color
ManimColor('#000000')
>>> 

The t0 example comes straight from the
Table
example in the documentation.

Thank you, but how could i make the condition, that, if i have the text "is a"  in that row then i want to do something, because the result Text("is a") is still of type vmobject, i cant just get the string "is a" off of that, nor can i say if the result is equal to Text("is a"), even when i tried to convert it to Tex and later use get_tex_string() it still doesnt work, i mean it should be something simple, that if i have written "is a"  in a cell then i want something to be done, but i cant find an answer, thank you

Just use str() to retrieve the needed string value. I added that to near the end of the example code.
